How to make the smoke follow the mesh, last for one frame or disappear after a certain distance?

I need the smoke to stay in the cloak. The cloak has cloth simulation, I tried giving it fluid collision effector, but it pushed the smoke even further outside.
Can I somehow make the smoke follow the mesh? Maybe I can give it gravity, make the smoke last for only one frame, or limit the distance?
I apologize for missing information:

The character is emitting smoke
The fluid domain is a simple cube covering everything
Here is the blend file


"The smoke" - which smoke? I see no smoke, I do not know what is the smoke emitter, where is the smoke domain, what are the settings?

@GordonBrinkmann, I am very sorry for that, I edited the post.
